# ClassNotFoundException when upgraded to Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, jdbc-pool

I recently upgraded my NetBeans IDE from v7.3 to v8 and all of a sudden my application throws an exception at server startup while connecting to DB. The only difference between these two versions of IDE are that the later one is using Tomcat 8.

## Exception Log:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory]
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:82)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:841)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:152)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:829)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:152)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:829)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:152)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:829)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:157)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.istore.core.listeners.AppContextListener.initdb(AppContextListener.java:44)
    at com.istore.core.listeners.AppContextListener.contextInitialized(AppContextListener.java:27)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5158)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:697)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:579)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:455)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1554)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1428)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:885)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:343)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1132)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:80)
    ... 58 more
```

## META-INF/context.xml

```
<!-- PostgreSQL Datasource -->
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" maxActive="50" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" name="jdbc/mydb" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:postgresql://myorg.corp.net:5432/mydb" username="abc" password="def" />
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The name of the default factory changed between Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 8. A couple of attribute names also changed. This is all as a result of switching from DBCP 1.x to DBCP 2.x in Tomcat 8. You want the following in your META-INF/context.xml file:

```
<!-- PostgreSQL Datasource -->
<Resource auth="Container"
          driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory"
          maxTotal="50"
          maxIdle="10"
          maxWaitMillis="-1"
          name="jdbc/mydb"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://myorg.corp.net:5432/mydb"
          username="abc"
          password="def" />
```

Since this factory is used by default for resources of type `javax.sql.DataSource` you can just drop that attribute all together. The other changes were:

```
maxActive -> maxTotal
maxWait   -> maxWaitMillis
```

Comment: Made changes as suggested but did not work. Still getting the same exception.

Comment: Grrr. Typo in the new factory package name now fixed.

Comment: Changed the factory package name but did not work either. Downgraded from NetBeans8 to NetBeans7 and it started working again. Looks like Tomcat8 has some problems.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory :(

Comment: @AlfredoM Sounds like you need to add commons-dcps2-x.x.x.jar into your classpath.  I've placed it in the `lib` folder.  See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/download_dbcp.cgi

Comment: Nice +1 this one works for tomcat8.

Answer (score 2):

You need `tomcat-dbcp-8.0.0-RC1.jar` in your `tomcat8` lib folder. The package structure for `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory` in `commons-dbcp.jar` is different from other `tomcat` versions.