# SpringBoot JNDI datasource throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-batch

Similar questions have been asked before and I went through all of those but not able to solve problem. Related Questions - [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712308/ubuntu-tomcat7-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-tomcat-dbcp-dbcp-bas/15880777#15880777),[Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573034/spring-boot-how-do-i-set-jdbc-pool-properties-like-maximum-number-of-connection),[Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711943/tomcat-dbcp-vs-commons-dbcp), [Q4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711943/tomcat-dbcp-vs-commons-dbcp), [Q5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518748/classnotfoundexception-when-upgraded-to-tomcat-8), [Q6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547934/error-starting-tomcat-context-with-spring-boot-java-lang-classnotfoundexception)

I have a Spring Batch project with Spring Boot and trying to use DB connection pools. I am using embedded tomcat container with version 8.5.x.

Everything works fine if I use application.properties to specify data source and pool settings.

But when I try to use JNDI, I get exception -

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory
```

I don't see any jar names `tomcat-dbcp-**` in Maven jars so I am not sure if I need to include any new dependency or need to set default data source factory and how to go about it.

Below is my JNDI beans set up, [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941829/how-to-create-jndi-context-in-spring-boot-with-embedded-tomcat-container). I have blanked out certain values.

```
@Bean
    public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory(){
        return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

            @Override
            protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(
                    Tomcat tomcat) {
                tomcat.enableNaming();
                return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
            }

            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();
                resource.setName("jdbc/myDataSource");
                resource.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
                resource.setProperty("driverClassName", "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
                resource.setProperty("url", "url");
                resource.setProperty("username", "user");
                resource.setProperty("password", "*****");
                context.getNamingResources().addResource(resource);
            }
        };
    }

    @Lazy
    @Bean(destroyMethod="")
    public DataSource jndiDataSource() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        bean.setJndiName("java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource");
        bean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
        bean.setLookupOnStartup(false);
        bean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return (DataSource)bean.getObject();
    }
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <groupId>***</groupId>
    <artifactId>***</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cu</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I am not sure about reason, was asked by folks higher up to do it. Probably, they don't want user name & passwords in properties file. What I find weird is spring boot is not including tomcat-dbcp dependencies as part of starter POM but using DBCP DataSource factory as default factory.

Comment: Are there any better ways to secure db connection information if we have to remain open for deployment to non - embedded environment too? One challenge that we face via class files is editing DB urls & users for various staging environments but distributing db information with war file doesn't seem a good idea.

Comment: You don't have to include it in files. You can pass it as arguments when starting your application or as environment variables. Also if you specify a datasource jndi name it will be used instead of the local configured instance. Instead of hacking your way into it, I suggest a read on how Spring Boot loads/resolves property files and how you can specify properties for environments. In short you should work with the framework not around the framework.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting `factory` attribute in my `Resource` Definition. `resource.setProperty("factory", "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory");`

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory(){
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(
                Tomcat tomcat) {
            tomcat.enableNaming();
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }

        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();
            resource.setName("jdbc/myDataSource");
            resource.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
            resource.setProperty("factory", "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory");
            resource.setProperty("driverClassName", "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
            resource.setProperty("url", "url");
            resource.setProperty("username", "user");
            resource.setProperty("password", "*****");
            context.getNamingResources().addResource(resource);
        }
    };
}
```

As per tomcat 8 documentation, it is supposed to automatically infer db pool factory type by looking at `DataSource` type and somehow it defaults to DBCP factory and that class is not there in my class path.

I guess so issue can be solved by making `tomcat-dbcp-**` jars available but I am not sure how to do that with spring boot or even if that is possible with spring boot.

What I find weird is Spring Boot not including tomcat-dbcp dependencies as part of starter POM but using DBCP DataSource factory as default factory.

Answer (score 3):

The “Starter POM” no longer includes jndi reltead dependencies, if you 
are using Tomcat/Jetty/etc... with JNDI you will now need to directly add this dependency yourself.

Then configure the JNDI in your application.properties file
    `spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/yourname`

For your exception, you need add the [tomcat-dbcp](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-dbcp/8.5.4) into your pom.xml file.

But you can check your project dependencies, if you use the spring-boot-starter-jdbc or spring-boot-starter-data-jpa ‘starters’ you
will automatically get a dependency to "tomcat-jdbc".

Comment: What would be those **jndi reltead dependencies** ? Also, I guess, I am setting same property in bean definition.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple choices :

- using the DBCP 2 datasource that is the default (you don't want to use DBCP 1 that is outdated and less efficient).
- using the Tomcat JDBC datasource.
- using any other datasource : for example HikariCP.

1) To use Apache JDBC datasource, you don't need to add any dependency as it is already provided in the Tomcat Spring Boot starter but you have to change the default factory class to  `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory` to use it.
You can do it in the resource declaration : 
`resource.setProperty("factory", "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory");`
I will explain below where add this line.

2) To use DBCP 2 datasource (which is actually expected by default) a dependency is required:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
  <version>8.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Of course, adapt the artifact version according to your Spring Boot Tomcat embedded version.

3) To use any other datasource, I will illustrate with HikariCP, add the required dependency if not already present in your configuration (it may be for HikariCP if you rely on persistence starters of Spring Boot) such as :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and specify the factory that goes with in the resource declaration :

```
resource.setProperty("factory", "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource");
```

For example with PostgreSQL and a DBCP 2 datasource, don't specify any factory as it is the default :

```
    @Override 
    protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {            
        ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();
        //...
        context.getNamingResources()
               .addResource(resource);          
    }
```

Here the variants for Tomcat JDBC and HikariCP datasource.

In `postProcessContext()` set the factory property as explained early for Tomcat JDBC ds :

```
    @Override 
    protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
        ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();       
        //...
        resource.setProperty("factory", "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory");
        //...
        context.getNamingResources()
               .addResource(resource);          
    }
};
```

and for HikariCP :

```
    @Override 
    protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
        ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();       
        //...
        resource.setProperty("factory", "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource");
        //...
        context.getNamingResources()
               .addResource(resource);          
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

to the preceding post. i think config for hikari might rather be sth like this:

```
resource.setProperty("type", "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource");
resource.setProperty("factory", "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariJNDIFactory");
```

it got me a bit further. then i was facing this exception leading to another dependency issue (missing oracle jdbc driver):

```
Failed to load driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setDriverClassName(HikariConfig.java:486) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
```

adding or removing >>>

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
>>>    providedRuntime 'com.zaxxer:HikariCP'
>>>    providedRuntime 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc'
}
```

to my gradle buildfile didnt make a difference. i also tried implementation and runtimeOnly scopes but it doesnt seem to affect the problem.

if anyone has ideas on how to propagate oracle jdbc driver (or basically any jar file, preferrably using gradle) to the **spring boot embedded tomcat**, please share your wisdom.

seems to be related to this: https://developpaper.com/maven-magic-hall-the-pits-on-which-oracle-jdbc-driver-depends/
maybe using this maven workaround it might work but i don't want to switch back to maven just for this.